# Wix Set an Environment Variable Conditionally at Runtime

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm using Wix 3.8, and I need to check to see if an environment variable is set at runtime - if it is not, I need to set it.  If it is, I must NOT overwrite the existing value.

From what I've seen, Wix offers  statements, and conditional pre-processor directives.  The former seems to be for "read only" type checks, as the element has not eligible child elements, such as .  The latter only runs at build time.

Do I have any other options, or must I use a custom action to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add code showing what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html), you should specify an `action=create`

> create
>
> ```
> Creates the environment variable if it does not exist, then set it during installation. This has no effect on the value of the
> ```
>
> environment variable if it already exists